# Finding right inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given a $3\times 4$ matrix $A$ such as 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
,$$ 
find a matrix $B_{4\times 3}$  such that
$$AB =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Apart from simply multiplying $A$ with $B$ and generating a $12$ variable system of equations, is there any simpler way of finding $B$ ?

Comment: Use products with 3x3 elementary matrices as row operations to reduce the original matrix to row echelon form. Then maybe something can be worked out.

Comment: I'm not looking for the inverse, meaning I don't want BA = I to be true. Just a matrix B that satisfies AB=I.

Comment: B could be a 4x3 matrix which leads to a 3x3 I with 1s on the main diagonal.

Comment: It would be clear for everyone to specific the specific matrix you want and I would suggest that you call it something other than $I$ to eliminate confusion.

Comment: Changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ 
has rank=$3$ and you can see that the square matrix $AA^T$ is invertible. Now note that $AA^T(AA^T)^{-1}=I$ so the matrix $B=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is a right inverse of $A$ (but it is not the unique).

in this case we have:
$$
AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}4&2&2\\2&2&1\\2&1&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
(AA^T)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}3&-2&-2\\-2&4&0\\-2&0&4\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B=\dfrac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}3&-2&-2\\1&2&-2\\-1&2&2\\1&-2&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following case:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\?&?&?\\?&?&?\\?&?&?\end{bmatrix}=I$$

Removing the first row, the remaining matrix is square:

$$\begin{bmatrix}?&?&?\\?&?&?\\?&?&?\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\-1&1&1\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&-1\\-1&1&1\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Of course there are infinite number of solutions