# Suppose $BAC=A$ where $A$ is a $k \times n $ matrix. What's the relation between $B$ and $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B, C$ be $k \times n$, $k \times k$, $n \times n$ matrices respectively. Suppose $A$ is fixed. I'm interested in conditions on $C$ that would ensure that there exists a $B$ s.t. $BAC=A$. Are there any such conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by relation? B and C have different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C$ is invertible we have
$$
BA=AC^{-1}
$$
Right multiply by $A^T$
$$
BAA^T=AC^{-1}A^T
$$
Note that $AA^T$ is a square matrix, and if it is invertible we have:
$$
B=AC^{-1}A^T(AA^T)^{-1}
$$

If $B$ and $A^TA$ are invertible we can do the same to the other side and find:
$$
C=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB^{-1}A
$$

Comment: So such a $B$ always exists? seems weird....

Comment: If $C$ and $AA^T$ are invertible, yes. If not... I'm not sure :(

Comment: When is $AA^T$ invertible?

Comment: Whan $A$ has full rows rank so it has a right inverse. See my answer to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487338/finding-right-inverse-matrix/1487375#1487375.

Comment: I've added something to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Last question: Now can we deduce the invertibility of $B$? obviously it's equivalent to invertibility of $AC^{-1}A^T$. What can we say about the invertibility here?

Comment: I suppose that if $A$ is full rows rank the inverse does exist.... but this have to be proved... (may be another question).